# Network Printer HP Officejet Pro 8610 no color model setting

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp, colors

I have an HP Officejet Pro 8610 connected to my Network and it shows up in Ubuntu printers and I can print but the problem is, that it only prints in RGB mode and I am not able to change the color model setting anywhere. I can only adjust the color mode such as color, grayscale etc.

Does anyone know how to change that?

Edit:
Even with hplip it doesn't work.

[image: printer settings]

Comment: Did you also install CUPS? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html.en

Comment: According to HPLIP site you need [at least 3.14.4](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) (for example Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has 3.16.3). You do not need proprietary plugin. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1. Cups is installed. HPLIP version is 3.17.10.

Answer (score 0):

Initially posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525809/341192).

In *System - Printers*, selecting the printer's properties, going to "Job options" (I guess 'Auftragoptionen' :)) - "Other options", down at the end there is an empty field to add a new option; fill that field with ***CNGrayscale*** and click "Add".

The new option is now listed under "Other options", but has an empty field: fill that with ***TRUE***, then click "Apply".

[image]

Now the new option *CNGrayscale* has a true/false switch that you can use to change between color and monochrome printing.